# Scaffold a controller for a model

Tags: asp.net-mvc

umm I am trying to create scaffolding controller in visual studio asp.net in MacBook m2 chip for my model student.cs and first I created the model class and then I tried to add scaffolded folder and then I chose mvc views using entity framework as this is what is need, then it asked me for the db context class options which have no idea about in details but I did it on windows I created the scfoodlede it asked me the model class to use and then I give it and it automatically added the dbcontext for me to use and then I was able to create CRUD